# "Adjugate" of an endomorphism of a finite-rank free module

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, exterior-algebra

If $M$ is a free module of finite rank $n$ over a commutative unitary ring and $a$ is an endomorphism of $M$, consider the endomorphism $\hat a$ of $M$ defined by the identity
$$
  x_1\wedge ax_2\wedge\dotsb\wedge ax_n =\hat ax_1\wedge x_2\wedge\dotsb\wedge x_n
$$
for all $x_1,\dotsc,x_n\in M$.
In any basis of $M$, the matrix of $\hat a$ is the [adjugate matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) of the matrix of $a$.

Is there a standard name for this "adjugate" endomorphism?
Is there a standard notation?

Comment: It seems that "adjugate endomorphism" was used in a former version of the Wikipedia article about Cayley-Hamilton's Thm.

Answer (score 2):

More generally, if $f : M \to N$ is a homomorphism between free modules of rank $n$, then we can define its "adjugate homomorphism" $\overline{f} : N \to M$ to be the composition
$$N \xrightarrow{\cong} (\Lambda^{n-1} N)^* \xrightarrow{(\Lambda^{n-1} f)^*} (\Lambda^{n-1} M)^* \xrightarrow{\cong} M.$$
This terminology is used in [arXiv:math/9907114](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9907114v1), Section 1.2.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know by any chance a French term for it? I will wait to see if there will be more answers.

Comment: Is the "bar" notation standard?

Comment: I don't know if this is standard. And I haven't looked for French words.